# Installing Sonar on Ubuntu with mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, sonarqube

I'm trying to get the nativ sonar package working on ubuntu 12.04. It's running and accessable on port 9000 when im running it with H2.

If i'm switching over to mysql - its not working, looks like DB-Connection fails. Logginname, table and permission are doublechecked severall times.

when i try to acces "`http://ip:9000/setup`" following message is displayed:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Please try back in a few minutes and contact support if the problem persists.
```

In the logfile i found folloing error:

```
2013.10.02 11:52:06 ERROR jruby.rack  unable to create shared application instance
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: no connection available
        from arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:517:in `set_native_database_types'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:61:in `initialize'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6:in `jdbc_connection'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2109:in `send'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1439:in `loop'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
        from file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440:in `initialize'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:74:in `automatic_setup'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:208:in `(root)'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1087:in `load'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:23:in `load_environment'
        from file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:65:in `load_environment'
        from <script>:1:in `(root)'

        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$4.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:231) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:58) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.init(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:33) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:48) [jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238) [jetty-servlet-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:482) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:281) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:67) [sonar-application-3.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:48) [sonar-application-3.7.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
        at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240) [wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [na:1.6.0_27]
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ConnectionNotEstablished) no connection available
        at arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.set_native_database_types(arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:517) ~[na:na]
        at JdbcConnection.initialize(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:61) ~[na:na]
        at JdbcAdapter.initialize(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).jdbc_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6) ~[na:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2109) ~[jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:na]
        at ConnectionPool.new_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionPool.checkout_new_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionPool.checkout(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188) ~[na:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1439) ~[jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:na]
        at ConnectionPool.checkout(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184) ~[na:na]
        at MonitorMixin.mon_synchronize(file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionPool.checkout(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionPool.connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionHandler.retrieve_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).retrieve_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115) ~[na:na]
        at Migrator.initialize(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).up(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).migrate(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).upgrade_and_start(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).automatic_setup(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:74) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).(root)(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:208) ~[na:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1087) ~[jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:na]
        at Rails2Environment.load_environment(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:23) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).load_environment(file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:65) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).(root)(<script>:1) ~[na:na]
2013.10.02 11:52:06 ERROR jruby.rack  Error: application initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: no connection available
        from arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:517:in `set_native_database_types'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:61:in `initialize'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6:in `jdbc_connection'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2109:in `send'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1439:in `loop'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
        from file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440:in `initialize'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:74:in `automatic_setup'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:208:in `(root)'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1087:in `load'
        from /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:23:in `load_environment'
        from file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:65:in `load_environment'
        from <script>:1:in `(root)'

        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$4.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:231) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:58) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.init(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:33) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:48) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238) [jetty-servlet-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:482) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:281) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:67) [sonar-application-3.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:48) [sonar-application-3.7.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
        at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240) [wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [na:1.6.0_27]
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ConnectionNotEstablished) no connection available
        at arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.set_native_database_types(arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:517) ~[na:na]
        at JdbcConnection.initialize(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:61) ~[na:na]
        at JdbcAdapter.initialize(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).jdbc_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6) ~[na:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2109) ~[jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:na]
        at ConnectionPool.new_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionPool.checkout_new_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionPool.checkout(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188) ~[na:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1439) ~[jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:na]
        at ConnectionPool.checkout(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184) ~[na:na]
        at MonitorMixin.mon_synchronize(file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionPool.checkout(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionPool.connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98) ~[na:na]
        at ConnectionHandler.retrieve_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).retrieve_connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).connection(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115) ~[na:na]
        at Migrator.initialize(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).up(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).migrate(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).upgrade_and_start(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).automatic_setup(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:74) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).(root)(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:208) ~[na:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1087) ~[jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar:na]
        at Rails2Environment.load_environment(/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:23) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).load_environment(file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:65) ~[na:na]
        at (Anonymous).(root)(<script>:1) ~[na:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/02 11:52:06 | 2013-10-02 11:52:06.525:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/},file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/02 11:52:06 | 2013-10-02 11:52:06.632:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000
```

Things i've tried:

- Setting the connector from "localhost" to IP
- Logging in via phpmyadmin and the credentials for sonar

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it works,

following approaches failed:

```
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?...
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/sonar?...
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://ipAdress:3306/sonar?...
```

with 127.0.0.1 worked, besides there were granted all access types in mysql

```
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sonar?...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because "bind-address" property in you mysql configuration (/etc/mysql/my.cnf) is set to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different setup, my MYSQL - instance is running on ip 192.168.0.35.
I specified the jdbc as
jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.35:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
and I connect to the database using
mysql -u sonar -p sonar -h 192.168.0.35
without any problem.
Bevor setting the right ip in sonar.jdbc.url I had a different error message, 
now it's the rack execption. So I am wondering if the Ip won't be passed further on
to the subsystems. Anyone got the same problems?

Comment: Okay, I don't know where the problem was though I got this error message I can see that sonar is up and running. Thanks.